# Sorting PHP by date modified results from glob

Tags: php

I need to go into a directory [named 'People'] and pull the names of folders and then construct some HTML that builds links using the contents of the directories.

I take a folder named: article-number-one and display a title, link, thumbnail, and excerpt based on the folder name.

Here is my code. It works except for the ordering. It is alphabetical. I want it to be by date created...newest on top:

```
<?php
$files = glob("people/*");
foreach($files as $file)
{
    echo '<div class="block"><a href="people/'.basename($file).'"><img src="people/'.basename($file).'/'.basename($file).'-thumbnail.jpg"  height="180" width="320" alt="'.basename($file).'"/></a><br/><br/>';
    echo '<a href="people/'.basename($file).'">'.str_replace('-', ' ', basename($file, "")).'</a><br/><div class="excerpt">';
    include 'people/'.basename($file).'/'.basename($file).'-excerpt.txt';
    echo '</div><hr></div>';
}
?>
```

Please help me to order the resulting HTML newest to oldest.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php http://php.net/manual/en/function.stat.php

Comment: I have looked both of those links over and have no idea how to proceed.

Comment: I found something :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this in several steps. This way you can check out how it proceeds and test each step separately.

```
// Get an array with all useful file info
$fileInfo = array_map(
    function($filename) {
        $short = basename($filename);
        // Excerpt
        $excerpt = $filename . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $short . '-excerpt.txt';
        if (is_readable($excerpt)) {
            $text = trim(file_get_contents($excerpt));
        } else {
            $text = 'Excerpt not available';
        }
        return [
            'full' => $filename,
            'base' => $short,
            'thumb' => $filename . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $short . '.jpg',
            'name' => ucwords(str_replace('-', ' ', $short)),
            'date' => filectime($filename),
            'text' => $text,
        ];
    },
    glob("people/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR)
);
```

To sort the array:

```
    // Now sort the array. Have a function decide when a file is before another
    usort($fileInfo, function($info1, $info2) {
        if ($info1['date'] < $info2['date']) {
            return 1;
        }
        if ($info1['date'] > $info2['date']) {
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    });
```

Finally you get the HTML in a variable. As a rule, it's good to have as few echo/print's as possible. Mixing PHP and output can be a maintenance nightmare.

```
// Get the HTML. You could put this in a .html file of its own
// such as 'template.html' and read it with
//          $template = trim(file_get_contents('template.html'));

$template = <<<INFO2HTML
<div class="block">
    <a href="{base}"><img
       src="{thumb}"
       height="180" width="320"
       alt="{base}"/></a>
    <br />
    <br />
    <a href="{base}">{name}</a>
    <br />
    <div class="excerpt">{text}</div>
    <hr />
</div>
INFO2HTML;

// Repeat the parsing of the template using each entry
// to populate the variables.

$html = implode('', array_map(
    function($info) use($template) {
        return preg_replace_callback(
            '#{(.*?)}#',
            function($keys) use ($info) {
                return $info[$keys[1]];
            },
            $template
        );
    },
    $fileInfo
));

print $html;
```

## Testing

```
$ mkdir people
$ mkdir people/joe-smith
$ echo "this is the excerpt" > people/joe-smith/joe-smith-excerpt.txt
$ touch people/joe-smith/joe-smith-thumbnail.jpg

$ ls -R people
people:
    joe-smith

people/joe-smith:
    joe-smith-excerpt.txt  
    joe-smith-thumbnail.jpg
```

Sample run outputs:

> ```
> <div class="block">
>     <a href="joe-smith"><img
>        src="people/joe-smith/joe-smith.jpg"
>        height="180" width="320"
>        alt="joe-smith"/></a>
>     <br />
>     <br />
>     <a href="joe-smith">Joe Smith</a>
>     <br />
>     <div class="excerpt">this is the excerpt</div>
>     <hr /> </div>
> ```

Comment: Hi...thanks for taking the time to answer. I copied all of that into a PHP file and it produces a blank page? I am new at this and a lot of the code snippets I find and try do not work. What am I missing? I need to add an echo statement?

Comment: I added an 'echo' statement and it returns incorrect html. I am trying to work with your code to correct the HTML. Fixing the image path was easy enough. I am trying to fix the pth so the HTML name shows up and the excerpt shows up.

Comment: This won't work with the folder structure I have chosen. Maybe I am looking at the problem incorrectly. Within the folder "people" there is a folder named "joe-smith". Within the folder "joe-smith" there are the following files I am using to build a page. The files are: index.php, joe-smith-thumbnail.jpg, joe-smith-excerpt.txt...my PHP snippet assembles the list of HTML and orders it by creation date.

Comment: I have fixed the array to display the filename without the dashes and I have fixed the HTML to display the image thumbnail. The excerpt is blank...I am working on it.

Comment: This also does not order these by date created. It is alphabetical.

Comment: I see, I hadn't visualized that folder structure. I'll see whether I can fix the code in a couple of hours when I get back.

Comment: I apologize...would you like to see an actual link to the page? Is it acceptable to add links?

Comment: http://hostinghtml.com/html/one/testing.php - if this isn't acceptable tell me and I will delete it. This is a test server so i can learn PHP.

Comment: Sorry, took way longer than expected. It looks like you got it to work! I checked the ordering part, but it works for me. Are you sure the names aren't already ordered *both* alphabetically and chronologically? Try creating first five.jpg, then four.jpg and so on. (Also, inside the function, invert the -1 and 1 return values to invert the sorting order).

Comment: Swapping the -1 and 1 ordered it correctly...but the excerpt .txt file is not part of the solution.

Comment: I had made a very silly mistake - used the wrong function to populate `$info['text']`. Now it should work, provided you supply it the correct path. You can use `die(var_dump($variable))` to inspect the content of a variable (for example the argument to `file_get_contents` to check the path, or the whole value of `$info`).

Comment: Thanks for the help. Changing the path doesn't look like it can be done in the html. I will search about what you mean about - die(var_dump($variable)).

Comment: I am not seeing any value being placed in the excerpt div

Comment: I've rewritten the code and tested it with a real case. Seeing as you're unfamiliar with some basic PHP functions, maybe you'd better get a programming tutorial first, though. Sorry that I used a style which isn't well suited for learning, I fear I have badly misread the situation.

Comment: Thanks for making the effort! I will keep at it!

Comment: @tonx in that case, you should mark the answer as accepted [the green check mark on the left]; you may want to check out the rules on Stack Overflow. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

```php
usort($files, function($a, $b) {
  return ($a['date'] < $b['date']) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Comment: Thanks again Sean...sorry :) I'll figure it out!